# auto generate a number in a field in dynamics crm 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a field in my form of a custom entity that I would like to be populated with an auto-generated number on form load. The number should start from 1000 for the first ever form record and for every new record it should increment like 1001, 1002 and so on.

I am not good with programming so I need help.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install one of the autonumbering solutions available on codeplex:

http://advcrm2011autonumber.codeplex.com/

http://crm2011autonumber.codeplex.com/

Personally I suggest the first one.

both are free

Comment: Thanks for the help Guido, you are a life saver.
do you know how to make it auto generate the number Onload rather than Onsave?

Comment: It will require some JavaScript code to "guess" the next number, but I suggest to don't modify the process (example, two users start to create a new record of your custom entity but both will have 1001 as number, after save one will get 1001, the other one 1002)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it by code :

```
var i = 0;
var n = 0;
$("body input:text").each(function(){
  if(i==0) n = 1000;
  else n++;
  $(this).val(n);
  i++;
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/ufJ56/2/

Comment: Hey Akram

As far as I think, your code will not start the number series from 1000. It will generate a number between 0 and 1 and then multiply it by 10000 and then add the result to 1000. 
How can it start the series from 1000?

And where do I set the name of the attribute field that will show the result on the form?

Comment: This is the method in javascript to generate a random number between two numbers (in this case 1000 and 11000), if you want to start the series from 1000, just replace the ramdom number by n = 1000; If you want to change the attribute field of your form who show the result, you can change the $("body input:text") by $("#myid") for id="myid" or $(".myClass") for class="myClass"

Comment: Replacing var n=0 to var n=1000 still does not start the series from exactly 1000 plus I want every new form to have a number one more than the previous one e.g, first form had the number 1000, the second 1001. Random generation of numbers wont get me that.

Comment: I updated my answer and the demo, now it does exactly what you want.

Comment: Yes it does Akram Fares, Thank you